# Синхронизация списка в ListView с сервисом

Tags: android, listview, service

Разрабатываю медиаплеер. У меня есть `ArrayList<File> songList` ,в который я добавляю файлы с девайса. Так же имеется модель Track, в которой есть поля такие как название песни, исполнитель,альбом. Затем эти  трэки Track я заношу в `List<Track> tracklist`.
Вопрос,собственно, в чем... Я пытаюсь реализовать функцию сортировки плейлиста по какому-либо полей вышеописанных полей модели

```
 public List<Track> sortViaSongTitle(List<Track> trackList) {
    Collections.sort(trackList, new Comparator<Track>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Track lhs, Track rhs) {
            return lhs.songTitle.toLowerCase().compareTo(rhs.songTitle.toLowerCase());
        }
    });
    return trackList;
}
```

На выходе я получаю отсортированный список в ListView .но в сервис я же передаю ArrayList songList и текущую позицию для воспроизведения беру из него. соответственно в листвью элементы плейлиста в новом порядке, в сервисе в старом(до сортировки). Как их синхронизировать?

Comment: В чём заключается необходимость передавать список в сервис?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид  -  для этого
 uri = Uri.parse(songList.get(position).toString());

Comment: сервис у Вас проигрывает трек? Если так, то быть может передавать в него Uri.parse(trackList.get(position).toString())? Нежели весь список

Comment: создайте в `Track` поле типа `File`, и используйте один и тот же список в сервисе, и не в сервисе. Зачем вам 2 списка?